websocket congestion causes SMOOTHER character motion?
I'm making a multiplayer game in Unity with websocketsharp. Everything works as intended, except for one very noticable problem. The server is running 3 bot characters, just for the sake of testing. Every frame the server sends the new position data to the clients. On the client end, the motion of the bots is very jittery, until I start moving the clients character which sends data to the server, which is when the bot motion smooths out. The jitter is perfectly correlated with when I am not sending any input to the server. I have logs that say the incoming data is halved when it starts sending data, so I know it is congesting the websocket, which is understandable and needs optimization, but my question is why would congestion cause SMOOTHER motion, and how can I get smooth motion over the network even when not congested
One thing I tried was just making the client send a single byte of code to the server every single frame. And what do you know, the bots motions weren't jittering. Congesting the websocket with a single extra byte had the same effect as 10-20 bytes per frame when actually sending important input to the server. Why does a single garbage byte sort of fix the problem? Obviously I don't want to fix it this way, and would prever to send as little data as possible.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
